# Reshape data.frame with two columns into multiple columns with data (R)

Tags: r, casting, dataframe, reshape, melt

A trivial question but I cant find the answer as of yet.

I want to split the dataframe column 'year' into a set of new columns with each year the column name and subsequent data below it:

```
    Year     FQ
   1975  3.156
   1975  8.980
   1977 10.304
   1977  7.861
   1979  4.729
   1979  7.216
   1981  4.856
   1981  3.438
   1983  9.887
   1983  3.850
```

desired output:

```
1975    1977    1979   1981    1983 

3.156   10.304  4.729  4.856   9.887
8.980   7.861   7.216  3.438   3.850
```

sample data:

```
d<-structure(list(Year = structure(1:10, .Label = c("1975", "1975", 
"1977", "1977", "1979", "1979", "1981", "1981", "1983", "1983", 
"1985", "1985", "1987", "1987", "1988", "1988", "1991", "1991", 
"1993", "1993", "1995", "1995", "1997", "1997", "2000", "2000", 
"2001", "2001", "2003", "2003", "2005", "2005", "2007", "2007", 
"2009", "2009", "2011", "2011"), class = "factor"), FQ = c(3.156, 
8.98, 10.304, 7.861, 4.729, 7.216, 4.856, 3.438, 9.887, 3.85)), .Names = c("Year", 
"FQ"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 62L, 123L, 184L, 
245L, 306L, 367L, 428L, 489L, 550L))
```

I have tried melting the data:

```
melt(d, id.vars = "Year")
```

and then using cast:

```
cast(d, Year~value)
```

and reshape

```
d1<-reshape(d, idvar="Year", timevar="FQ", direction="wide")
```

but to no avail

Comment: Is it always 2 lines per `Year`?

Comment: no, I have just used this for an example. It varies depending on what analysis is being done. so it maybe 365 lines in one analysis then 61 lines in another

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really have an "ID" variable, so you need to create one. It will be easier if `Year` was a `character` variable, so I've done that transformation below, in addition to adding an "ID" variable:

```
d <- within(d, {
  Year <- as.character(Year)
  ID <- ave(Year, Year, FUN=seq_along)
})
```

From here, it is easy to use `dcast` directly...

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(d, ID ~ Year, value.var="FQ")
#   ID  1975   1977  1979  1981  1983
# 1  1 3.156 10.304 4.729 4.856 9.887
# 2  2 8.980  7.861 7.216 3.438 3.850
```

... or `reshape`.

```
reshape(d, direction  = "wide", idvar="ID", timevar="Year")
#    ID FQ.1975 FQ.1977 FQ.1979 FQ.1981 FQ.1983
# 1   1   3.156  10.304   4.729   4.856   9.887
# 62  2   8.980   7.861   7.216   3.438   3.850
```

Comment: Excellent. nice and simple! However I would of thought a function somewhere would have been able to do this straight off, it seems not. thanks again!

Comment: @Salmosalar, I would say that both of these functions handle the data "straight off". The point is that for a given row/column combination, both of these functions look for a unique value, which is not present in your "Year" variable, so we had to create one. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Yes, thats where I was getting stuck!