# Plotting pairwise correlations in long melted column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has with 3 columns of melted data (long and thin) that I would like to create a pairwise scatterplot comparing the Genes (eg. Gene A vs Gene B, Gene A vs Gene C, Gene B vs C and so on) in a trellis for up to 10 genes.  I started using geom_point() but couldn't figure out the best way to pass the x and y values in the aesthetics so I started looking at other options like pairs,splom, plotmatrix for pairwise data but I think the data would need to be converted to a format that has each gene as a column and the values in rows.

It seemed straightforward at first but I'm a newbie to R/ggplot and couldn't seem to find an adequate solution online.

```
ID  Gene    value
830 Gene_A  1.8
831 Gene_A  0.4
832 Gene_A  2.5
833 Gene_A  2.3
834 Gene_B -5.1
835 Gene_B  3.6
836 Gene_B  2.0
837 Gene_B  3.2
837 Gene_C -1.6
838 Gene_C -1.4
839 Gene_C -5.5
840 Gene_C -4.4
841 Gene_D -2.7
842 Gene_D -3.2
843 Gene_D -2.5
844 Gene_D -2.5
```

Comment: which values of each gene should be plotted against which values of other genes?  They all have different ID numbers

Comment: The ID numbers are not relevant in this context and can be ignored (sorry for huge confusion. I am just looking to plot the values of each the genes against one another.

Comment: Minnow, I have tried geom_ point () with x=value but couldn't figure out what to supply to y for the next gene, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to work this out using the following code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot)

#first convert data to generate new ID for each gene
dat$ID<-NULL
dat<-within(dat,{Gene<-as.character(Gene)
ID<- ave(Gene,Gene,FUN=seq_along)
})
```

see this link for information as example on reshaping this type of data frame
[Reshape data.frame with two columns into multiple columns with data (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373797/reshape-data-frame-with-two-columns-into-multiple-columns-with-data-r)

```
#cast the new dataset with 1 id per gene, convert from long to wide
dat<-dcast(dat, ID~Gene,value.var="value")

#setup new data frame for plotting
dat4plot=dat

#need to remove ID for plotting
dat4plot$ID=NULL 

#Generate plot using pairs function,removed upper panel to see better
pairs(dat4plot,pch=21,bg="red",upper.panel=NULL)
```

[image: Pairwise Plot]

I'm happy with this but also open to more efficient suggestions !!!